# Java lambda type inference not working as expected in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

Why does this piece of Java code not compile in Kotlin without the explicit type parameter in `Collectors.toList<String>()`? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

```
// works
List<String> folders = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
            .filter(it -> it.toFile().isDirectory())
            .map(it -> it.toAbsolutePath().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// does not compile - resulting type is `MutableList<in String!>..List<Any?>?` which is not compatible to `List<String>`
val folders: List<String> = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
            .filter { it.toFile().isDirectory }
            .map { it.toAbsolutePath().toString() }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())

// compiles
val folders: List<String> = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
            .filter { it.toFile().isDirectory }
            .map { it.toAbsolutePath().toString() }
            .collect(Collectors.toList<String>())
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, Kotlin has its own `File.walk` extension method.

Comment: You've stumbled upon a bug in type inference https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11259

Comment: @Ilya Thanks for the link - great that there's already a ticket.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this piece of Java code not compile in Kotlin without the explicit type parameter in `Collectors.toList<String>()`?

This looks like a compiler bug to me. I recommend creating an issue in [Kotlin (KT) | YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

> Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Yes. As [Kirill Rakhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075117/java-lambda-type-inference-not-working-as-expected-in-kotlin#comment65504798_39075117), "Kotlin has its own `File.walk` extension method." e.g.:

```
val folders: List<String> = File(args[0]).walk()
        .filter(File::isDirectory)
        .map(File::getAbsolutePath)
        .toList()
```

If you prefer using Java 8 streams then checkout [Kotlin/kotlinx.support: Extension and top-level functions to use JDK7/JDK8 features in Kotlin 1.0](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.support). It defines a `Stream<T>.toList()` function:

```
val folders: List<String> = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
        .filter { it.toFile().isDirectory }
        .map { it.toAbsolutePath().toString() }
        .toList()
```

Comment: I'd like to add that `Stream<T>.toList()` is already in the standard library of coming Kotlin 1.1 https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1-M1/libraries/stdlib/jre8/src/kotlin/streams/Streams.kt#L35

Comment: Hi, when i'm using the File(path).walk() method, the list contains only the name of the Directory from path, but not the files inside this directory. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found two ways to make it work without explicitly specifying generic type in both places.

Either you can specify full type of variable with [generic covariance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)

```
val folders: MutableList<in String> = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
        .filter { it.toFile().isDirectory }
        .map { it.toAbsolutePath().toString() }
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or you can simply let Kotlin do its type inference for variable (not generic parameter of method)

```
val folders2 = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))
        .filter { it.toFile().isDirectory }
        .map { it.toAbsolutePath().toString() }
        .collect(Collectors.toList<String>())
```

Comment: `MutableList<in T>` is rarely a result one expects to get from `collect`. Second workaround is ok.